# Super tiny bugs in store bought raspberries

Tags: food-safety, raspberries

For a while now, I've been seeing incredibly tiny bugs in store bought raspberries. They survive refrigeration and I can rinse them off (I think, can't be sure due to their size). They are really really small so I can't take a picture. They look like a little dot and do not fly.

I'm a bit concerned if they may be damaging to health. Does anyone know what they are and is rinsing the raspberries enough?

Comment: How tiny?  Do they have wings or not? What color?  

Fresh organic berries will have a number of harmless insects, but it really depends on what bugs those are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its probably pretty natural for there to be tiny little bugs in the fruit. One thing you can do is soak them in a bath of cold water, lemon juice and maybe a splash of white vinegar, but not too much as you don't want them to take on that vinegar taste. You can spray them down with baking soda and lemon mixed with water as well. This will help draw the bugs out.

Comment: I was looking for this link. This blog has some great information about how to make home made veggie/fruit washes. Its really cheap too!! https://wellnessmama.com/28/diy-fruit-and-vegetable-wash/

Answer (score 3):

Probably harmless.

I'd go back to the store and tell them about it.

If unsure, do not eat them and find another store.

Answer (score 0):

Those bugs you see occur in berries of all sorts. They're the larvae of fruit flies. Although they are not harmful, you can soak them in salt water if you want to rid of them.